# Validation Rule to find a duplicate value

Tags: custom-field, validation, validation-rule, business-logic

I need to create a custom field, say REG_NO__c(text) which allows N/A multiple times but should not allow duplicate values from ST001-ST999,

I tried to make it as unique(case insensitive), but it also find N/A as duplicate.
Any validation rule works?

Any suggestion please, Thank You!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may not be able to achieve with Validation rules. You can achieve it by defining Matching rule and Duplicate rule with condition that field is not equal to NA.

[image]
Please find the below resources for Matching rule and Duplicate rules.

[Matching Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=matching_rules_overview.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

[Duplicate Rule](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=duplicate_rules_create.htm&language=en_US&release=206.5&type=0)

Comment: Thanks SaiPraveen, it is working but when user enters duplicate data, it shows warning and allowing to save with duplicate data. Is there anyway to restrict that.